# how to convert bytes to txt file again and save in given directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, io, byte

There is file as bytes in book.

```
class tobinary:
    def binarydata(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
            blobdata = bytearray(file.read())
            return blobdata


    def download(self, book):
        tmsg.showinfo("notice", "Select path to save file.")
        destination = fd.askdirectory()
        # source=(io.BytesIO(book.read()))
        source = Image.open(io.BytesIO(book))
        print(source)
        shutil.copy((source), destination)
        tmsg.showinfo('confirmation', "file saved!")


    def upload(self, bookname, book_f, window, r):
        ojct = tobinary()
        Label(window, text=bookname).grid(row=r, column=0)
        Button(window, text="download", command=lambda: ojct.download(book_f)).grid(row=r, column=1)
```

error

> p = os.fspath(p)  expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not
> _io.BytesIO
>
> error after giving bytes
>
> raise TypeError("Can't mix strings and bytes in path components") from
> None TypeError: Can't mix strings and bytes in path components

Comment: As the error said, the first argument to `shutil()` should be a filename but `source` is not.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why you are trying to use `grid` on the output of `ojct.download` it doesn't return a tkinter object.

Comment: @scotty3785 ojct.download is a function called in command for button and it does returns a tkinter object.